# Om based application inside React based application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a video component written in ClojureScript (based on Om) and a page written in JavaScript (based on React) and I want to use that video component in that page. They do not interact with each other, video component is completely autonomous. I came up with the following code, which works, but I'm not sure if it's OK to have ClojureScript app inside React app:

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  render: () => {
    return <div><div id="video"></div><Comments/></div>;
  }
}

React.render(<Page/>, document.getElementById('page'), function() {
  // video is an instance of ClojureScript application
  video.client.render({id: 'abc'});// calls React.render(<VideoPlayer/>, document.getElementById('video'));
});
```

It results in the following DOM:

```
<div id="page">
  <div>
    <div id="video">
      <CljsVideoPlayer/>
    </div>
    <Comments/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it OK to include a ClojureScript component into a React based page like this?

Comment: Is your question whether this code looks okay to us?

Comment: No, my question is whether it's OK to include ClojureScript component into React based page this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are never calling `om/root`, your component shouldn't use any of the unique features that om provides: instrumentation, listening to transactions, etc.

In that case, you've effectively written a React component in cljs + om, and things should work without problems.

If you want to make sure, post a gist with the component and we'll check if it assumes any om provided functionality, that is not provided by React.